# How to use mock location in React Native - Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-gps

I'm trying to write react native module for changing GPS location in android studio. I'm setting permission and set application name in mock location developer settings. After that also, its not working and also not getting any error. These is my sample code,

```
    @ReactMethod
    private Context mContext;
    public void mockLocation(String gps, Callback callback) {
        LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
          mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
          mLocationManager.addTestProvider
                  (
                          LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                          "requiresNetwork" == "",
                          "requiresSatellite" == "",
                          "requiresCell" == "",
                          "hasMonetaryCost" == "",
                          "supportsAltitude" == "",
                          "supportsSpeed" == "",
                          "supportsBearing" == "",

                          android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW,
                          android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE
                  );

          Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

          newLocation.setLatitude (22.5726);
          newLocation.setLongitude(88.3639);

          newLocation.setAccuracy(500);

          mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled
                  (
                          LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                          true
                  );

          mLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus
                  (
                          LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                          LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                          null,
                          System.currentTimeMillis()
                  );

          mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation
                  (
                          LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                          newLocation
                  );
        callback.invoke("Location changed");
      }
```

And my react code is,

```
componentDidMount() {
    RNNativeToastLibrary.mockLocation("gps", (res) => {
      console.log(res)
    });
  }
```